# Compiling on RaspberryPi by using make

Tags: c, makefile, raspberry-pi2

When I use make to compile the RaspberryPi's source code, the error happens like this:
"bmp180.c:(.text+0xe8): undefined reference to `bcm2835_i2c_write'"

However, I have used the "-l bcm2835", the makefile as follow:

```makefile
#makefile

bmp: main.o bmp180.o 
    gcc -o bmp main.o bmp180.o

main.o: main.c bmp180.h 
    gcc -c main.c -l bcm2835.h

bmp180.o: bmp180.c bmp180.h 
    gcc -c bmp180.c -l bcm2835.h


clear:
    rm -f main.o bmp180.o
```

Comment: `-l bcm2835.h`this is wrong, -l is for linking library while the `.h` files are header files. Try `-l bcm2835`

Comment: Thanks, it works. ".h" is the file, not the dynamic shared libraries.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have `-l bcm2835.h` in your Makefile.  The name of the library is simply `bcm2835`.  Files ending with `.h` are files meant to be `#include`'d in your C source; they are not dynamic shared libraries.

Additionally, shared libraries are required at the *link* stage, not the *compile* stage; you will need to add `-l bcm2835` to the linking step:

```
bmp: main.o bmp180.o 
    gcc -o bmp main.o bmp180.o -l bcm2835
```

The `-l` arguments in your compile steps are effectively no-ops (but they won't hurt anything).

Comment: Thanks a lot. It works. 
the key reason is what you said, the ".h" file is not dynamic shared libraries.